# JQuery - Responsive string trimming conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interesting problem. I'm trying to responsively shorten the length of all text with the class 'ideaDescription' based on the screen width. The problem is, I run a function to reduce the size of the text, and then this becomes the new 'ideaDescription'. I'm not sure if the best thing to do would be to store the descriptions in an array? Or is there a better way?

```
<p class="ideaDescription">Lorem ipsum dolor ... condimentum.</p>
<p class="ideaDescription">More lorem ipsum dolor ... condimentum.</p>

$(document).ready(function () {

            function addEllipsis() {
                $('.ideaDescription').each(function addEllipsis() {

                var thisText = $(this).html()
                var maxLength = $(window).width()/4;

                if (thisText.length > maxLength) {
                    var trimmedString = thisText.substr(0, maxLength);

                    trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));

                    trimmedString += '...<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>';

                    this.innerHTML = trimmedString;
                }
            });                 
            };

            addEllipsis();

            $(window).resize(function () {
                addEllipsis();
            });
});
```

Comment: Why not use CSS text-overflow property? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

Comment: @kurt CSS text-overflow generally only works on a single line

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I think I'm gonna give up for the moment and stick with a set character count. I'm super new to JS so I'm gonna get myself some more experience before I jump into DOMs etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `DotDotDot` that will do this for you. You can find it [here.](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) Note that the library is no longer actively maintained but I still use it and it works really well.

You would use it something like this, as long as `ideaDescription`'s height is responsive:

```
$('.ideaDescription').dotdotdot({watch: "window"})
```

You can also pass a callback function to the `dotdotdot` call that receives two parameters, `isTruncated`(boolean) and `orgContent`(the original content).

```
$('.ideaDescription').dotdotdot({watch: "window", function(isTruncated, orgContent){ *do something* });
```

Edit: `dotdotdot` seems to require the element you are trying to truncate to have a defined size in the CSS, so you may have to do something like this first:

```
$('.ideaDescription').css('height', $('.ideaDescription').outerHeight());
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion. I tried dotdotdot before, but I'm having problems cutting the paragraph at the right time. Sometimes it works, but the properties of my text boxes change depending on the screen size which seems to confuse it. At the moment it is not adding "..." on small screens but the text is still being cut.

Comment: @OwenFfrancon Interesting...I do know that the text boxes have to have an explicit size set on them for `dotdotdot` to work properly. In my app I have a container for `title` and `description` divs, and I have to explicitly set the size of the container to the size of those divs. I will update my answer, maybe it will help.